# Binding Items collection on Menu to be shown on MenuItem Popup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the need to have a custom Menu (AMTMenu class inheriting Menu plus some additional DependencyProperties) with a MenuItem (a hamburger button actually) with dynamic children, since this menu is to be reused in a lot of layouts. Other than that, it should show other 5 TopLevel menu items that display info contained on the DataContext without any children attached and a refresh button. It's working fine except for the sub menu part which is not being shown when I click the hamburger MenuItem because I can't seem to bind the items correctly. Here's the code I have so far:

```
<Menu.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid Name="ContentGrid"
              Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Width}"
              IsItemsHost="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="HamburgerButtonColumn" Width="5*" />
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ButtonsColumn" Width="90*" />
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RefreshButtonColumn" Width="5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <MenuItem Foreground="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}"
                      Focusable="False"
                      Template="{DynamicResource MainMenuButtonTemplate}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="Menu"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                MinHeight="20" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <UniformGrid Name="ButtonsUniformGrid"
                         Grid.Column="1"
                         Columns="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:AMTMenu}}, Path=ButtonCount}"
                         Rows="1"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <MenuItem Grid.Column="0"
                          Template="{DynamicResource OiButtonsTemplate}"
                          Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag, Converter={StaticResource OiMainMenuButtonsColorBrushConverter}}"
                          Focusable="False"
                          Command="{Binding ShowRefreshDataCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="Button1">
                    <MenuItem.Tag>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MainMenuButtonsTextConverter}" ConverterParameter="INC">
                            [ ... MultiBinding logic ... ]
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </MenuItem.Tag>
                </MenuItem>

                [ ... XAML Code for the other 4 MenuItems ... ]

            </UniformGrid>
            <DockPanel Name="PART_Refresh"
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

                [ ... XAML Code for the refresh button ... ]

            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Menu.Template>
```

As for the hamburger MenuItem, I have the following template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MainMenuButtonTemplate"
                 TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ContentControl x:Name="PART_Button"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                            Focusable="False" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" 
               AllowsTransparency="true"
               Focusable="false"
               HorizontalOffset="1"
               IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
               PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}"
               Placement="Bottom"
               VerticalOffset="-1">
            <Border BorderThickness="2"
                    BorderBrush="White"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer"
                              CanContentScroll="true"
                              Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                    <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"
                                        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
                                        Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true"
                                        Margin="2"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" TargetName="PART_Button"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush}" TargetName="PART_Button"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Finally, I'm declaring the Menu and submenu with the following XAML:

```
<local:AMTMenu x:Name="MainMenu"
                   DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                   DataContext="{Binding CurrentModel}"
                   IsButton1Visible="True"
                   IsButton2Visible="True"
                   IsButton3Visible="True"
                   IsButton4Visible="True"
                   IsButton5Visible="False">
    <MenuItem Header="Item 1" />
    <Separator />
    <MenuItem Header="Item 2" />
    <Separator />
    <MenuItem Header="Item 3" />
</local:AMTMenu>
```

How can I bind the Items collection on the Menu to be shown on the hamburger MenuItem popup?

Comment: Do you have a view model backing up your view? Inside the view model, you can define an ObservableCollection that can notify the view once they're being updated

Comment: I do but what does it have to do with my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem, posting here to help anyone who has a similar problem... The issue was that the hamburger MenuItem was declared on the template so, the Menu wasn't getting any children and consequentely not firing the IsSubmenuOpen property on the MenuItem. After I realized this, the solution was pretty simple, replaced the MenuItem on the Template with an ItemsPresenter and moved the MenuItem to the Menu content. Also, and since the Menu now has Items defined in its class, I can't declare the sub menu as I was doing previously, it would only replace my default item, so I had to use a new DependencyProperty called SubMenuItems.

Here's the final code:

AMTMenu.xaml

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid Name="ContentGrid"
                  Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Width}"
                  IsItemsHost="True">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="HamburgerButtonColumn" Width="5*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ButtonsColumn" Width="90*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RefreshButtonColumn" Width="5*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
                                Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" />
                <UniformGrid Name="ButtonsUniformGrid"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Columns="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:AMTMenu}}, Path=ButtonCount}"
                             Rows="1"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <MenuItem Grid.Column="0"
                              Template="{DynamicResource OiButtonsTemplate}"
                              Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag, Converter={StaticResource OiMainMenuButtonsColorBrushConverter}}"
                              Focusable="False"
                              Command="{Binding ShowRefreshDataCommand}"
                              CommandParameter="Button1">
                        <MenuItem.Tag>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MainMenuButtonsTextConverter}" ConverterParameter="INC">
                                [ ... MultiBinding logic ... ]
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </MenuItem.Tag>
                    </MenuItem>

                    [ ... XAML Code for the other 4 MenuItems ... ]

                </UniformGrid>
                <DockPanel Name="PART_Refresh"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

                    [ ... XAML Code for the refresh button ... ]

                </DockPanel>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Menu.Template>
    <MenuItem Foreground="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}"
              Focusable="False"
              Template="{DynamicResource MainMenuButtonTemplate}"
              AllowDrop="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:AMTMenu}, Path=SubMenuItems}">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="Menu" MinHeight="20" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Menu declaration on parent View:

```
<local:AMTMenu x:Name="MainMenu"
               DockPanel.Dock="Top"
               DataContext="{Binding CurrentModel}"
               IsButton1Visible="True"
               IsButton2Visible="True"
               IsButton3Visible="True"
               IsButton4Visible="True"
               IsButton5Visible="False">
    <local:AMTMenu.SubMenuItems>
        <local:SubMenuItemsCollection>
            <MenuItem Header="Item 1" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Item 2" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Item 3" />
        </local:SubMenuItemsCollection>
    </local:AMTMenu.SubMenuItems>
</local:AMTMenu>
```

Where SubMenuItemsCollection is just a class that derives from ObservableCollection

```
public class SubMenuItemsCollection : ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> { }
```

Hope this helps someone in the future ;)